# In-app purchase creation and usage of development subscription groups

Tags: ios, swift, in-app-purchase, subscription

I am new to `in-app purchases`. According to the `App Store` requirements, I need to create a subscription group. This group is only for testing the `in-app purchase` in development. Once the app moves to production, I think I am supposed to use different subscription group.

Is this possible? How can one specify which subscription group is to be used to fetch products in the app?

I have read many posts related to `in-app purchases`, but was unable to find an answer. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I have one more doubt , If I create a test subscriptions group in iTunes connect, Can delete it?

Comment: Why not create a test subscriptions group in iTunes connect and see for yourself?

Comment: I don't see why you would create a different subscription group for testing and release. Subscription group details are not visible via the Store Kit framework. You just fetch the product codes you want. If the subscription group is important then you need to code that logic in your app somehow; either hard code it or retrieve the data from your own server.